# Insert Cursor Into PHP Drop Down On Page Load

Tags: php, javascript, html

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Firstly, apologies, I'm sure this is a really simple fix, but I just can't find the answer.

I'm using the script below to create a drop down menu. Once a value has been selected from it, the relevant records are retrieved.

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function ajaxFunction(name) 
{ 
var browser = navigator.appName; 
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") 
{ 
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 

} 
else 
{// code for IE6, IE5 
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 

} 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{ 
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
{ 
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
} 
} 

xmlhttp.open("GET","getfinds.php?dateoftrip="+name,true); 
xmlhttp.send(); 
} 

function getquerystring() { 
var form = document.forms['frm1']; 
var word = form.word.value; 
qstr = 'w=' + escape(word); // NOTE: no '?' before querystring 
return qstr; 
} 

</script> 

<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
.style1 { 
    font-family: Calibri; 
    font-size: 14px; 
} 
--> 
</style>

</head> 
<body onLoad="document.forms.getfinds.name.focus()" > 

<form action="getfinds.php" method="get" name="getfinds"> 
<input name="field" type="hidden" id="field" value="">
<table width="148" border="0"> 

<tr> 
<td width="152"><p class="style1">Select a date from below</p> 
  <div align="center"> 
    <?php 
include("db.php"); 

$query="SELECT dateoftrip FROM finds GROUP BY dateoftrip ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC"; 
echo '<select onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value)"><option name="name" value="allrecords">Show All Records</option>';
$result=mysql_query($query); 
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

echo "<option name='name' value=".$rows['dateoftrip'].">".$rows['dateoftrip']."</option>"; 

} 
echo "</select>"; 
?> 
  </div></td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</form> 
<div id="my_div"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I'm trying to find a way of inserting the cursor in the drop down menu on page load.

I've tried using the following:`<body onLoad="document.forms.getfinds.dropdown.focus()" >` but when I run the script I receive the following error: `document.forms.getfinds.dropdown is null or not an object.`

As I said, I do apologise for the simple question, but I've been looking for a while for the answer.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your select statement to:

```
echo '<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="ajaxFunction(this.value)">
```

Change your `<body>` to:

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('dropdown').focus()" >
```

Comment: True but that wasn't what my answer was focusing on. It was just trying to solve his problem which it does. But I will add it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Removed the -1 as he isn't trying to submit this field but is using it as an AJAX control only; though my answer is complete from the get-go.

Answer (score 1):

Take the `name="name"` attribute out of your `<option>` tags.

Add the attribute `name="dropdown"` to your `<select>` tag.

Then your `onLoad` will work fine. No need to change it.

`<option>` tags do not support the name attribute.

Read More:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp